# How to remove particular renderer for multipleseries renderer in scatter graph using achartengine lib?

Tags: achartengine

How to remove particular renderer for multipleseries renderer in scatter graph(in combined graph) using achartengine lib

Comment: what u really want show some code/snap/detail?

Comment: int k1=mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount(); 
  System.out.println("Count before removing whiteRenderer...."+k1);
  
  mRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(whiteRenderer);
  
  
  int k2=mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount(); 
  System.out.println("Count after removing whiteRenderer."+k2);

Comment: Im using 2 renderers but i want to display one renderer at a time after some delay(i.e one after the other).prob is its not removing from above code

Answer (score 0):

The `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` class extends `DefaultRenderer`, which has a method `removeSeriesRenderer(SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer)`.

Comment: I had used that method still its not removing